# angular2 rc6: Property queryParams does not exist on type RouterState

Tags: angular

Another "Deprecation-Now-Error" on the road to angular 2 final.

The error-message is clear, I just need to know what the corresponding field is called now. Anybody?

> Property queryParams does not exist on type RouterState

Answer (score 14):

**Think I solved it**: The property "queryParams" is now on the property "root" of the Routerstate:

```
this.router.routerState.root.queryParams
```

Answer (score 10):

Probably u are using:

```
router: Router
```

You can change that to:

```
activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
```

Then to access the queryParams:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams
```

Comment: it worked in angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snapshot version

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
) {}
```

instead of

```
this.router.routerState.snapshot._root.value.queryParams;
```

i did this

```
this.route.snapshot.queryParams;
```

Comment: snapshot does not exist on type route. angular 6