# Angular2 queryParams throws "does not exist on type" error

Tags: javascript, angular

I got an Angular2-service that should return parameters from an URL like http://localhost:3001/?foobar=1236

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute }     from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class ParameterService {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {  }

  getParameter() {
    return this.route.snapshot.queryParams.foobar;
  }
}
```

But when I call the getParameter() method of the service I get the error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'foobar' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: any; }'
```

and after the error it returns the correct result. I can access the foobar parameter with the debugger without any problems. did someone had a similar issue? I could imagine that it gets called to early?

(possible duplicate: [angular2 rc6: Property queryParams does not exist on type RouterState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344301/angular2-rc6-property-queryparams-does-not-exist-on-type-routerstate))

Comment: At 2019 with angular 8 you could use `this.route.params.subscribe((params) => { const foobar = params.foobar; })`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how you get parameters:

```
this.route.snapshot.queryParams['foobar'];
```

Comment: thanks man! I found it out two minutes after posting ... always the same :/

Comment: Also, note that if you're using paramMap then (ex) use `const routeParam = paramMap['params']['id'];` to avoid this type error.